# How can I track the movements of 4 particular blobs using EmguCV C#?

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

The goal of my school project is to compare 2 images of a lattice structure to then calculate a central deformation.
First I binarize my image and apply an erosion filter to have all the nodes of my lattice.
Then I do a blob detection using `SimpleBlobDetector` to have the coordinates of all my nodes and I pick 4 blobs near the center and save the coordinates of their center and their number.

**Picture of the lattice structure :**

[image: lattice_picture]

**Image after binarization, erosion and contours detection :**

[image: Base image]

**Filters used :**
Binarization

```
CvInvoke.AdaptiveThreshold(imgGray, imgBinarize, 255, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.AdaptiveThresholdType.GaussianC, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Binary, 120, 0);
```

Erosion

```
imgErode = imgBinarize.Erode(6);
```

---

The Problem is that I thought it would be quiet simple because I thought you can just took the number of the 4 blobs and compare the coordinates between the base image and the deformed one and just calculate the distance using Pythagoras' theorem to have the movement in pixel. But after trying this method I saw that the number of almost all the blobs have changed so it is not possible to juste take the number. As you can see in the image, the blob i wanted to compare was the one in the green circle (blob 122) on the left image but in the deformed image on the right the blob 122 is in the green circle so it doesnt correspond to the previous one.

[image: blob detection 2 images]

For the moment I dont have any solutions in mind since I'm a bit new to image processing so I would gladly take any help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Could be answered better if you edited your post to let us see how you programmatically achieved all these effects on the image.

Comment: yes, I too would like to see the unfiltered source image. the applied filtering is likely improvable appreciably. -- "pythagoras theorem", we call that "euclidean distance", or just distance. -- yes, blob indices vary because every picture is different. you need to track blobs. you do that by finding the nearest blob in the new frame, for each blob you're tracking. yes, that means you have to calculate the distance of your old tracked blob to every blob in the new frame, and then pick the closest one, assuming it's close enough to be plausibly "the same" blob.

Comment: I've edited my post with the original picture used before filtering, added what methods i used to filter my image. And yes it may be the only way to pick the closest blob and pray to be the good one, I will try to set this method and see the result

Comment: @ThomasHerr There's still no code of your actual tracking algorithm though.